# Acumatica: decimal places and bold text on custom field

Tags: acumatica

does anyone know how to change the decimal places displayed for a custom calculated field? Right now it is displaying 12 decimal places, and I only want it to display 2.

Also, I am trying to bold the font of a custom field on a screen. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of decimal places can be defined in you PXDBDecimal/PXDecimal attribute of your custom field

Eg:

```
[PXDBDecimal(2)] // 2 decimal places
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.00")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Quantity", IsReadOnly = true)]
public Decimal? PQty { get; set; }
```

For the Bold font, i dont know any attributes available. May be you should try  customizing your ASPX or there are many advanced properties like CSSClass available in the customization project > screen > control > properties.

Comment: the CSS customization was the way to go for bolding the font. Thanks for that tip!
for some reason I don't have the decimal attribute in my field. I tried adding it, and the calculation wasn't being performed once I did this. I do have 2 fields performing a calculation. The first one does have that decimal attribute and the 2nd field that multiplies it by hundred does not have the decimal attribute.

Comment: nevermind. I figured it out. I added the PX decimal attribute and it worked :-) thanks!

Comment: could you share your what exactly you did for the BOLD? as it will be a good information to share.

Comment: if you use the inspect element feature in Google Chrome (other browsers as well, I think Internet Explorer is the only one that doesn't work with this)  and inspect the field you want to bold, you can trace that back into the actual CSS file and do a search for what you found using the inspect element. And then change it there.